# No funciona el formulario ni guarda la info en el localStorage

Tags: javascript, formularios, function, input, local-storage

En este código se intenta que funcione el formulario y cargue los datos de la mascota que el usuario introduzca y a su vez guarde dichos datos en el localStorage del navegador. Al respecto, por consola no aparece ningún error donde pueda guiarme... he ido depurando con console.log pero aparentemente todo está bien, incluso observando con detalle me doy cuenta que en el localStorage aparece brevemente por unos 2 segundos algo como "tk_localstorage_test" y su valor es true, por lo que presumo está guardando correctamente pero no encuentro por qué no funciona el formulario y por qué no guarda la info en localStorage

```
class Pet {
    constructor(petId, petName, petSize, petWeight, petAge, petDangerousToHumans, petDangerousToPets, petSick, petInSpecialTreatment){
    this.petId = Number(petId);
    this.petName = petName.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + petName.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    this.petSize = petSize.toLowerCase();
    this.petWeight = petWeight.toLowerCase();
    this.petAge = Number(petAge);
    this.petDangerousToHumans = petDangerousToHumans.toLowerCase();
    this.petDangerousToPets = petDangerousToPets.toLowerCase();
    this.petSick = petSick.toLowerCase();
    this.petInSpecialTreatment = petInSpecialTreatment.toLowerCase();
    }
    petRoom = 0;
    details(){
        return `<li>Nombre: ${this.petName}</li>
        <li>Tamaño: ${this.petSize}</li>
        <li>Peso: ${this.petWeight}</li>
        <li>Edad en años: ${this.petAge}</li>
        <li>Peligroso para los humanos: ${this.petDangerousToHumans}</li>
        <li>Peligroso para las demás mascotas: ${this.petDangerousToPets}</li>
        <li>Se encuentra enferma: ${this.petSick}</li>
        <li>Requiere tratamiento especial: ${this.petInSpecialTreatment}</li>
        <li>Número de habitación: ${this.petRoom}</li>`
    }
}

class PetsRoom {
    constructor(petsCapacity,roomNumber){
        this.petsCapacity = petsCapacity;
        this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
        this.pets = [];
        this.petsInside = this.pets.length;
    }
    addPet(pet){
        if (this.petsInside < this. petsCapacity){
            this.pets.push(pet.petName);
            this.petsInside += 1;
            pet.petRoom = this.roomNumber;
            return `Se a agregado a ${pet.petName} a la habitación ${this.roomNumber}.`
        } else {
            return `No se pueden agregar más mascotas en la habitación ${this.roomNumber}` 
        }
    }
    removePet(pet){
        if (this.pets.indexOf(pet.petName) > -1){
            this.pets.splice(this.pets.indexOf(pet.petName),1);
            pet.petRoom = 0;
            return `Se a removido a ${pet.petName} de la habitación ${this.roomNumber}`
        } else {
            return `${pet.petName} no se encuentra en la habitación ${this.roomNumber}`
        }
    }
}

let dogsRooms = [new PetsRoom(3,1), new PetsRoom(3,2), new PetsRoom(2,3), new PetsRoom(5,4), new PetsRoom(3,5), new PetsRoom(2,6), new PetsRoom(2,7), new PetsRoom(1,8), new PetsRoom(1,9), new PetsRoom(1,10),]

let dogsInShelter = [new Pet(1,'lola', 'pequeño', 'sobrepeso', 2, 'no', 'no', 'si', 'no'), new Pet(2, 'paco', 'grande', 'desnutrido', 5, 'no', 'no', 'no', 'si'), new Pet(3, 'simon', 'gigante', 'ideal', 2, 'si', 'no', 'no', 'no'), new Pet(4, 'pico', 'mini', 'delgado', 2, 'no', 'no', 'no', 'si'), new Pet(5, 'tomas', 'mediano', 'obeso', 2, 'no', 'si', 'no', 'no'), new Pet(6, 'lucas', 'grande', 'ideal', 2, 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no'), new Pet(7, 'sofia', 'pequeño', 'delgado', 2, 'no', 'no', 'si', 'no')]

let lastPetAdded = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('newDogs'));

dogsInShelter.push(lastPetAdded)

dogsRooms[0].addPet(dogsInShelter[0]);
dogsRooms[2].addPet(dogsInShelter[1]);
dogsRooms[2].addPet(dogsInShelter[2]);
dogsRooms[3].addPet(dogsInShelter[3]);
dogsRooms[3].addPet(dogsInShelter[4]);

let listDogs = document.querySelector('.lists__pets');

updateHTML(dogsInShelter);

let incomeForm = document.querySelector('.income__form');

incomeForm.addEventListener('submit', addPet);

listDogs.childNodes.forEach((dogDetails)=>{
    dogDetails.addEventListener('click',(dogInList)=>{
        let dogToShow = document.querySelector(".lists__petDetails");
        dogToShow.innerHTML = dogsInShelter.find(dogInShelter => dogInShelter.petId==dogInList.target.id.slice(-1)).details();
    })
})

function addPet(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    let incomeForm = document.querySelector('.income__form');
    let newId = dogsInShelter[dogsInShelter.length-1].petId + 1;
    let isDangerousForHumans = 'no';
    let isDangerousForOtherPets = 'no';
    let isSick = 'no';
    let needSpecialTreatment = 'no';

    if (incomeForm[4].checked){
        isDangerousForHumans = 'si'
    }
    if (incomeForm[5].checked){
        isDangerousForOtherPets = 'si'
    }
    if (incomeForm[6].checked){
        isSick = 'si'
    }
    if (incomeForm[7].checked){
        needSpecialTreatment = 'si'
    }
    const newDog = new Pet (newId, incomeForm[0].value, incomeForm[1].value, incomeForm[2].value, incomeForm[3].value, isDangerousForHumans, isDangerousForOtherPets, isSick, needSpecialTreatment);
    dogsInShelter.push(newDog);
    localStorage.setItem('newDogs', JSON.stringify(newDog));
    listDogs.innerHTML = "";
    updateHTML(dogsInShelter);
    incomeForm.reset();
}

function updateHTML(dogsToShow){
    for (let i = 0; i < dogsToShow.length; ++i){    
        listDogs.appendChild(createDogsList(i,'li'));
    }
}

function createDogsList(i,container){
    let dog = document.createElement(container);
    dog.innerText = dogsInShelter[i].petName;
    dog.id = 'pet' + dogsInShelter[i].petId;
    dog.className += "dog"
    return dog
}







<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ms+Madi&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <h2 class="header--title animate__animated animate__rotateInDownLeft"><a href="../index.html">CulturAnimal</a></h2>
    <form class="header--form animate__animated animate__zoomInLeft">
      <input type="text" name="searchBar" id="searchBar" class="header--searchBar">
      <input type="button" value="Buscar" class="header--searchButton">
    </form>
    <nav class="nav animate__animated animate__zoomInLeft">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.html"><i class="fas fa-home nav--icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="./services.html"><i class="fas fa-heart nav--icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Servicios</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-wrench nav--icon"></i>Tools</a></li>
        <li><a href="./team.html"><i class="fas fa-users nav--icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Equipo</a></li>
        <li><a href="./contact.html"><i class="far fa-address-card nav--icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main class="tools">
    <section class="income">
      <form class="income__form">
        <label for="income__petName">Nombre de la mascota a ingresar:</label>
        <input type="text" name="petName" id="income__petName" required>
        <select name="income__petSize" id="forms__size" required>
          <option value="" selected disabled>Tamaño</option>
          <option value="mini">Mini</option>
          <option value="pequeño">Pequeño</option>
          <option value="mediano">Mediano</option>
          <option value="grande">grande</option>
          <option value="gigante">gigante</option>
        </select>
        <select name="income__petWeight" id="forms__weight" required>
          <option value="" selected disabled>Peso</option>
          <option value="desnutrido">Desnutrido</option>
          <option value="delgado">Delgado</option>
          <option value="ideal">Ideal</option>
          <option value="sobrepeso">Sobrepeso</option>
          <option value="obeso">Obeso</option>
        </select>
        <label for="income__petAge">Edad de la mascota:</label>
        <input type="number" name="Edad" id="income__petAge" required>
        <div class="income__petDangerousForHumans">
          <h5>¿Es peligroso para los humanos?</h4>
          <input type="checkbox" name="dangerousForHumans" id="isDangerousForHumans">
        </div>
        <div class="income__petDangerousForOtherPets">
          <h5>¿Es peligroso para las demás mascotas?</h4>
          <input type="checkbox" name="dangerousForOtherPets" id="isDangerousForOtherPets">
        </div>
        <div class="income__petSick">
          <h5>¿Se encuentra enferma la mascota?</h4>
          <input type="checkbox" name="petSick" id="isSick">
        </div>
        <div class="income__specialTreatment">
          <h5>¿La mascota necesita un tratamiento especial?</h4>
          <input type="checkbox" name="specialTreatment" id="needAnSpecialTreatment">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Cargar">
        <input type="reset" value="Limpiar">
      </form>
    </section>
    <section class="animatedRooms">
      <div class="animatedRooms__container"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="lists">
      <div class="lists__container">
        <h3 class="lists__pets--title">Mascotas en el refugio.</h3>
        <ul class="lists__pets"></ul>
      </div>
      <div class="lists__petDetails"></div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer--social">
      <p>Siguenos en</p>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square footer--icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram footer--icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter footer--icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube footer--icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer--info">
      <h2 class="footer--info__h2"></h2>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer--contact">
      <p>Contáctanos</p>
      <a href="#"><i class="far fa-envelope footer--icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp footer--icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/42f502ebab.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya probé tu código en mi navegador y me indica un error al momento de obtener el valor de la variable **petName**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La sintaxis de tus localStorage esta correcta, para validarlo creé otra localStorage llamada **exampleLocalStorage** en tu función **createDogsList**...

```
function createDogsList(i,container){
    localStorage.setItem("exampleLocalStorage", "Este es el valor");
    let dog = document.createElement(container);
    dog.innerText = dogsInShelter[i].petName;
    dog.id = 'pet' + dogsInShelter[i].petId;
    dog.className += "dog"
    return dog
}
```

...  el localStorage se creó de forma correcta y puedo verla en la consola de mi navegador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te recomiendo que valides que tu variable **petName** está siendo inicializada correctamente.

**-------- Actualización --------**

Agregué un **console.log()** dentro de tu funcion **createDogsList**, para poder validar que tu objeto **dogsInShelter** se esté poblando corréctamente:

```
function createDogsList(i,container){
    let dog = document.createElement(container);
    console.log(dogsInShelter[i]);
    dog.innerText = dogsInShelter[i].petName;
    dog.id = 'pet' + dogsInShelter[i].petId;
    dog.className += "dog"
    return dog
}
```

Como puedes ver en la siguiente imagen, el objeto contiene 7 elementos correctos pero el 8vo elemento es **nulo**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces hace todo sentido que te salte el siguiente error cuando se intenta leer el 8vo elemento de tu objeto **dogsInShelter**:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'petName')

Comment: Justo ese es el problema, que he ido debugeando el código con console.log y aparentemente todo va bien pero... ¿por qué ese error?

Comment: @OtroMasComoTu creo que el error está al poblar tu objeto dogsInShelter en tu función createDogsList. He editado mi respuesta para agregar la imagen y entiendas mejor a lo que me refiero.

Comment: Ok, entiendo ahora mucho más el error y su causa pero no así la solución... ¿cómo debería seguir recorriendo el objeto para que pueda mostrar correctamente "n" mascotas sin que solo sea hasta la séptima? es decir ¿cómo debería poblarlo correctamente entonces?

Comment: Pues @RobertoRivera veo que sería normal que arroje "null" pues el objeto solo tiene 7 instancias y no 8

Comment: @OtroMasComoTu pues a mi me pinta 8 campos, 7 con datos y 1 null

Comment: Pues en ese caso... ¿cuál sería la solución?

Comment: @OtroMasComoTu amigo, te recomiendo que hagas una corrida de escritorio (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJeDk29YCgM) en la parte de tu código donde metes los valores a tu objeto 'dogsInShelter', de esa forma podrás darte cuenta en que punto estás ingresando un valor nulo. Necesitas depurar línea por línea tu código para que puedas analizar concienzudamente. Suerte!